# Unable to get right Website response with POST?

Tags: html, post, web, plsql, get

I would like to get the response of a website that has results posted by a form. I've tried using WebClient, WebRequests, etc.

Current Code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var buffer = client.UploadValues("https://secure.monroecc.edu/pls/bpr1/bwzkfcls.P_GetCrse", "POST", vals);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Count());
}
```

Also pretty sure that the current code isn't wrong it's just missing something. When I do get the response of the website it's wrong, it's the page where you would fill out the form.

If you try to GET the website it results in this error on the website itself (without posting the variables that go along with it):

```
VARIABLES IN FORM NOT IN PROCEDURE: 
NON-DEFAULT VARIABLES IN PROCEDURE NOT IN FORM: TERM_IN,SEL_SUBJ,SEL_CRSE,SEL_TITLE,BEGIN_HH,BEGIN_MI,BEGIN_AP,SEL_DAY,SEL_PTRM,END_HH,END_MI,END_AP,SEL_CAMP,SEL_SCHD,SEL_SESS,SEL_INSTR,SEL_ATTR,SEL_LEVL,SEL_INSM

DAD name: bpr1
PROCEDURE  : bwzkfcls.P_GetCrse
URL        : http://secure.monroecc.edu:63500/pls/bpr1/bwzkfcls.P_GetCrse
PARAMETERS :
===========
```

Here's an image of the request being sent. (Viewing using Chrome)

[image: chrome view]

I know that the website usses oracle PLSQL but again that doesn't seem to help me with retrieving the results of the search.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the source of a website".  This is by definition impossible. An HTTP request to a server will return a stream of data, assembled by the server, whose type will be indicated by the `Content-type` header.  You must explain what it is you expect to get back when you POST your request.

Comment: @JimGarrison source is really supposed to mean response, and when I send my POST request I expect to get the response with a list of classes. I hope that clarifies a bit, editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the form using the following code:

```
private void Run(string[] args)
        {
            NameValueCollection vals = new NameValueCollection();
            vals.Add("TERM_IN", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_SUBJ", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_CRSE", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_TITLE", "");
            vals.Add("BEGIN_HH", "");
            vals.Add("BEGIN_MI", "");
            vals.Add("BEGIN_AP", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_DAY", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_PTRM", "");
            vals.Add("END_HH", "");
            vals.Add("END_MI", "");
            vals.Add("END_AP", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_CAMP", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_SCHD", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_SESS", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_INSTR", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_ATTR", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_LEVL", "");
            vals.Add("SEL_INSM", "");

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var buffer = client.UploadValues("https://secure.monroecc.edu/pls/bpr1/bwzkfcls.P_GetCrse", "POST", vals);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Count()));
                //Console.Read();
            }
        }
```

It returns a 200 status code and valid html indicating that the form was received properly. However, since none of the values are correct the returned page says that there is a missing form element that must be included (NAME NOT FOUND FOR PIDM: )

The parameter mismatch error you are receiving means that the parameters you are passing in are not the ones that the stored procedure expects. You'll need to get an exact list of the parameters and expected values first, then you can just plug them in and this should work. Unfortunately the page returns a 200 status code so you'll have to parse out somehow whether there was an error or not.

Comment: Ok, Not sure what your getting at though. I have values for this provided by the chrome form data image in my question but I still get the wrong page response. I understand I'm trying to reverse engineer this a bit but unfortunately its not going so well.

Comment: It means that the error is coming from the stored procedure rather than the web server. You need to know which parameters the stored procedure requires in order for this to work. I get the impression you don't control the server or have access to the database to check the stored procedure. I doubt there is a way to query for the parameters since that would likely be considered a security risk for the database.

Comment: Right, so even if the website gives me the non-default variables in procedure not in form, they might not be all the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Use a GET request instead of a POST.

Comment: @Nate, is that a question or a statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a page that follows a form to give you a result set when it never actually receives the form variables that would make the result possible.

Your variable `vals` which should pass the set of variables never does.

```
VARIABLES IN FORM NOT IN PROCEDURE: 
NON-DEFAULT VARIABLES IN PROCEDURE NOT IN FORM: TERM_IN,SEL_SUBJ,SEL_CRSE,SEL_TITLE,BEGIN_HH,BEGIN_MI,BEGIN_AP,SEL_DAY,SEL_PTRM,END_HH,END_MI,END_AP,SEL_CAMP,SEL_SCHD,SEL_SESS,SEL_INSTR,SEL_ATTR,SEL_LEVL,SEL_INSM
```

This response error says that it never received any of the variables listed.  I would trace back in your code to the location were you name and assigned your list of variables to the Collection `vals`.  Check for proper spellings and proper assignment.

Comment: I should note that I do pass in the variable with vals in the first code block when I run it I'll get the actual page but the wrong one. When I don't include variables that page 404 shows up with that data

Comment: I said that in my question (without posting the variables that go along with it):